# Debugging Javascript code into Dev Tools Chrome

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm learning to debug code in DevTools Chrome. I encountered the following problem when working with such a task.

```
 function Access(arr1, arr2) {
  let sorty= arr1.concat(arr2).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a == b) {
      
      return 0;
    }
    if (a < b) return -1;
  });
  debugger;
  // console.log(sorty);
  return sorty.filter((beg,end)=>{
    console.log ('beg: ' , beg,'   end: ', end);
    console.log ('indexOf(beg): ', sorty.indexOf(beg), "   indexOf(end): ", sorty.indexOf(end));
    return sorty.indexOf(beg)===end});
}
console.log( 'p'+ Access([1,4,3,5],[3,7,8,4,5])+' s');
```

In the debug panel stack, I see two incoming arrays, one glued and sorted array. But the array that is obtained during the last check for indexOf can't be found anywhere. It only appears at the end of the function. How do I see where the array is being written during the indexOf check?
And the second question.
I have console.log statements in the function itself.
And then there is a function call via console.log - the very last line. Why is the letter "p" written before the output of a fully processed array when calling the function? As I assumed, the letter "p" should have appeared before the output of the elements and indexes of the array.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWXhD.png)

thanks for any help.

Comment: `sorty.filter((beg,end)=>{` what you're calling `beg` and `end` are actually the current element passed to the function and its index.

Comment: meaning, `sorty.indexOf(beg)` is alwasy equal to `end`

Comment: while `sorty.indexOf(end)` doesn't really make sense, that is trying to find the index of an index...

Comment: @GrafiCode what I wrote in console.log is my attempts to randomly find a way to see the generated array in the string return sorty.indexOf(beg)===end});. And the fact that there is no sense in the called operators was so conceived. I was looking for all the options where at least something comes when called. But again, I did not find either through console.log or through debug how and where the array is gradually formed by the string return sorty.indexOf(beg)===end});. In the debug step-by-step mode, the array output appears only when it is fully processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` to debug the gradually-forming array, since it lets you use an accumulator (declared as `a` in this example):

```js
function Access(arr1, arr2) {
  let sorty= arr1.concat(arr2).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a == b) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a < b) return -1;
  });
  return sorty.reduce((a,beg,end)=>{
    let ret
    if (sorty.indexOf(beg)===end) {
      ret = a.concat([beg])
    } else {
      ret = a
    }
    debugger
    return ret
  }, []);
}

console.log('p' + Access([1,4,3,5],[3,7,8,4,5]) + 's');
```

[image]

To answer your second question, your code `console.log( 'p'+ Access([1,4,3,5],[3,7,8,4,5])+' s');` is concatenating strings, and it will only output when `Access()` is returned.

This shows how `p` is output first, using three different `console.log()`

```js
function Access(arr1, arr2) {
  let sorty= arr1.concat(arr2).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a == b) {
      
      return 0;
    }
    if (a < b) return -1;
  });
  debugger;
  // console.log(sorty);
  return sorty.filter((beg,end)=>{
    console.log ('beg: ' , beg,'   end: ', end);
    console.log ('indexOf(beg): ', sorty.indexOf(beg), "   indexOf(end): ", sorty.indexOf(end));
    return sorty.indexOf(beg)===end});
}

console.log('p');
console.log(Access([1,4,3,5],[3,7,8,4,5]));
console.log('s');
```